# Can Lego soccer (football) parts be used for anything other than soccer?

Tags: piece-usage

I had the Lego soccer field, but took it apart. What else can the parts be used for besides soccer?  I'm specifically wanting to know about the green bases and minifigure stands.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The green parts are great to make a green smooth field, which is kinda obvious. Landscaping is one usage, and if you find it too uniform, don't forget you can cover some areas with additionnal hills or whatever. The Technic hole in there can come handy as you can easily attach [something](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/2476b) in it. Since it'll rotate freely, your added decoration can even be placed at an angle. Trees come to mind too: you can attach them to the Technic hole too, and maybe fill the green curved area with brown 1x1 round plates to symbolize earth.

The fact that it's green isn't always the most important aspect; sometimes you'll just need a big horizontal flat surface just for its flatness. I've used some of these parts (tan ones) to create a flat layer udner a SNOT river (basically a wall of blue bricks on the side). Doing that with 2x2 tiles would have been cumbersome, and more importantly I could use parts which I usually have no use for. In my specific case, the fact that they can be attached on duplo bricks was a plus.

The minifig stands aren't that much useful, but the spring in them means you can hope to build interesting mechanisms, especially projectile ones. Have a look at the [instructions of set 7020 — Army of Vikings with Heavy Artillery Wagon](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7020-1#ui-tabs-6), the designer of that set did an excellent missile launcher with it.

Don't get me started on [what to do with the soccer balls](http://www.greatballcontraption.com/).

Answer (score 3):

[Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/)s information about [Sports Minifig Stand](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30488c01&in=S), has information on where it's used in some sets that are not sports-related. For example:

- [Viking Ship](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7018-1)
- [Troll Assault Wagon](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7038-1)
- [Troll Warship](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7048-1)

I don't own any of these sets, so I don't know exactly *how* this piece is used in there - maybe someone else can give information about that.

The [Sports Field Section 8 x 8](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30492&in=S) has only been used for Sports sets (soccer and [basketball](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=3432-1)).

Comment: I suppose the Vikings designer was in love with that part. I've only built 7020 and I didn't know about the others, but I guess the usage is similar in all sets: launch some form of missile using the spring power. But I think the magazine mechanism in 7020 is really a nice touch. Fire up to 10 projectiles without rloading!

Comment: The Minifig Stand that appears in the Viking and Troll sets is black and not white like in the football set.

Comment: @Ambo100: as you can see on the photo in the question, football-sets include black _and_ white ones.

Answer (score 3):

The minifigure stands make great commodes if you ever build a scene with a restroom.